# igraph.vs R igraph coping to dataframe or list

Tags: r, igraph

In below code, how can I copy content of `final_list` into a list or into a new data frame?

`final_list` is `"igraph.vs"` class object and the last line of the code is giving me an error: Error in V(final_list) : Not a graph object

```
library("igraph", lib.loc="C:/Users/njog/Documents/R/win-library/3.0")  

g1 <- graph.formula(a-+d, a-+b, a-+c, c-+b, b-+e)
E(g1)
V(g1)
succesors=neighborhood(g1,"a",order=vcount(g1), mode="out")[[1]]
predecessors=neighborhood(g1,"e",order=vcount(g1), mode="in")[[1]]
final_list_numbers=intersect(succesors,predecessors)
final_list=V(g1)[final_list_numbers]
class(final_list)
final_list
V(final_list)$names
```

Comment: "giving me an error." what error?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee  Error in V(final_list) : Not a graph object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `final_list$name` to get the names of the vertices.

```
> final_list$name
[1] "a" "b" "c" "e"
```

See `?igraph::attributes`.
Near the bottom:

> Similarly is `vs` is a vertex set `vs$name` gives the values of the name attribute for the vertices in the vertex set.

(In `?V` you can see that `V` returns a vertex set).